# Facebook Conversion API - Not Received Test Server Events for app

Tags: facebook, testing, events, facebook-graph-api, conversions-api

We Start for implement Facebook Conversion Api for App events.

We Setup conversion api by manual

Not received any server event in test event tool , specially this case: `"action_source": "app"`.

We done this steps in facebook developer

- Create Facebook app and connect it with the verified business account.
- Adding IOS/Android Platform

We done this steps in event manager

- Link App with new pixel
- Generated access token

We generated Access Token using events manager to allow setup conversion api manual
[guideline for generate token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/get-started/)

For Testing Server Events we used Graph API Explorer [Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=POST&path=2463075093847992%2Fevents&data=%5B%7B%22action_source%22%3A%22app%22%2C%22app_data%22%3A%7B%22advertiser_tracking_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22application_tracking_enabled%22%3Afalse%2C%22extinfo%22%3A%5B%22a2%22%2C%22com.some.app%22%2C%22771%22%2C%22Version%207.7.1%22%2C%2210.1.1%22%2C%22OnePlus6%22%2C%22en_US%22%2C%22GMT-1%22%2C%22TMobile%22%2C%221920%22%2C%221080%22%2C%222.00%22%2C%222%22%2C%22128%22%2C%228%22%2C%22USA%2FNew%20York%22%5D%7D%2C%22event_id%22%3A12345%2C%22event_name%22%3A%22TestEvent%22%2C%22event_time%22%3A1687344585%2C%22user_data%22%3A%7B%22client_ip_address%22%3A%22254.254.254.254%22%2C%22client_user_agent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64%3B%20rv%3A63.0)%20Gecko%2F20100101%20Firefox%2F63.0%22%2C%22em%22%3A%22f660ab912ec121d1b1e928a0bb4bc61b15f5ad44d5efdc4e1c92a25e99b8e44a%22%7D%7D%5D&test_event_code=TEST68424),

this is the example for data

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "action_source": "app",
      "app_data": {
        "advertiser_tracking_enabled": false,
        "application_tracking_enabled": false,
        "extinfo": [
          "a2",
          "com.some.app",
          "771",
          "Version 7.7.1",
          "10.1.1",
          "OnePlus6",
          "en_US",
          "GMT-1",
          "TMobile",
          "1920",
          "1080",
          "2.00",
          "2",
          "128",
          "8",
          "USA/New York"
        ]
      },
      "event_id": 12345,
      "event_name": "TestEvent",
      "event_time": 1687346413,
      "user_data": {
        "client_ip_address": "254.254.254.254",
        "client_user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0",
        "em": "f660ab912ec121d1b1e928a0bb4bc61b15f5ad44d5efdc4e1c92a25e99b8e44a"
      }
    }
  ],
  "test_event_code": "TEST68424"
}
```

after we put the correct Pixel id, Access Token, Test event code..

We not received any event in test event tool !!

while we expected received events in test tool.

Answer (score 0):

The above json is working fine just change event time to latest one. It will show up in test events

Comment: event time is update with correct one .. but still the event not appear in test events, please note this just when set source action as "app"

Comment: Did you tried from payload helper? Because the above posted payload is working with a different "test_event_code" generated from my side.
The best way to test it, create a new payload from payload helper and set action source as "app". If its showing in your dashboard, then try to add above parameters one by one and test it.

Answer (score 0):

We phased the same issue. I believe it is an issue with the facebook SDK. Not sure if it is just with the Test Event tool and in production is working as expected.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34842798)